# Windows OpenedFilesViewer. Strange unaccountable file handles

Tags: windows-10, malware, handle

If using the nirsoft’s OpenedFilesViewer, which prints file handles. There are some “processes” with strange chinese characters that have a handle on inexistent files on C: drive. I haven’t paid much attention to it, since I can’t find the files nor the process, of which one has PID 4 i.e. the NT Kernel & System process. But it still doesn’t look right and I am worried if it in fact is malware, since it appears on every boot.

Examples:

C:躋 (appears every boot)

C:ᅐ鎩ᅐ鎩Ј (other files vary in names)

[OpenedFilesViewer list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulFPG.jpg)

If I try to close the handle C:躋 or kill the process it won’t work.

Comment: Maybe delete the files  with Unlocker (MajorGeeks)

Comment: @John How would that work if the files do not exist/can't be found?

Comment: Download and run MalwareBytes (it is free) http://malwarebytes.com/

Comment: It seems the files must exist somewhere on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but as stated, Unlocker can’t find the file, in fact it doesn’t list any file on the C: drive root. I have run Malwarebytes @Gantendo. First I thought it’s a bug on openedfilesview, or a mistranslation of hex, but it seems to only affect me.

Comment: To rule out that it is a bug, try https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: I have used Process Explorer, Process Hacker, Autoruns, Procmon. They don’t show anything like it. I think they all use the same API. Either it is a bug, or ofview shows me something alarming. Even though I block internet connections by default, it bugs me to see chinese letters.

Comment: I think Process Explorer uses Handle https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle Do you have the latest version of OpenedFilesViewer? Maybe report it as a bug.